# Path issue in Swift framework binary

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, frameworks

**The situation:**

I am inheriting a project built in `Swift 2` over the previous year by engineers who left the company before I joined.

The project consists of two frameworks with dependencies on *Stephen Celis*' `SQLite.Swift` framework, which need to be distributed to Business Units all over the world as binary files rather than private Cocoapod repositories, because of corporate policies.

**The issue**

Any framework I compile (whether ours or Stephen Celis') contains hardcoded paths of the form `/Users/myaccount/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Untitled-cbiuymbtgddcooadzhacxrxlrtfd/Build/Intermediates/SQLite.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SQLite iOS.build/Objects-normal/i     386/SQLite.swiftmodule^@/Users/myaccount/Documents/SQLite.swift-master/SQLite/Core/` where I'd expect `@rpath` based ones. (The example here being SQLite.swift).

I have been looking for a way to tell Xcode (Version 7.3.1, 7D1014) to use relative paths in the binary but couldn't figure it out. Where is my approach wrong?

Comment: Where are you getting those hardcoded paths from? Is it from the build output? On the Build Settings?

Comment: @MobileBen that's part of what I'd like to find out (I've figured out the problem came from hardcoded paths because Xcode yells it doesn't have permissions when we try to compile using the framework binaries on another account), and a quick search through the binary revealed the paths to be hardcoded, where they were `@rpath` a few months ago (as evidenced in a former version of the framework).

Comment: Got it, so you looked at the binary for the framework. Have you gone into Build Settings to see what the Dynamic Library Install Name and Dynamic Library Install Name Base are?

Comment: @MobileBen they are both `@rpath'`ed, but Apple replied to my Ticket with a definitive "sorry unsupported", so I'll just have to convince management to work it out differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started a Code-Level Support Ticket, but Apple close-and-refund'ed it on the grounds that "Distributing binary Swift frameworks remains unsupported in Xcode 8.".

I'm afraid that for now, this objective remains out of my reach.